# Ember Component classNameBinding not binding

Tags: ember.js, components

I have a component that is a button which needs to change it's classNames via a property of it parent component/controller:

```
// components/my-button/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'button',
    classNameBindings: ['classNames'],
    // some other unrelated stuff following....
});
```

it's template:

```
// components/my-button/template.hbs
{{text}}
// nothing important here exept the test-output of:    
{{classNames}}
```

and I insert it like this in another component:

```
// component/parent-component/template.hbs
{{my-button
    classNames=variableClassNames
    text='foo'
}}


// components/parent-component/component.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    isSortableDown: Ember.computed('track.sort', 'maxSort', function() {
        return this.get('track.sort')<this.get('maxSort');
    }),

    variableClassNames: Ember.computed('isSortableDown',function() {
        if(this.get('isSortableDown')) {
            return 'btn btn-xs btn-default';
        } else {
            return 'btn btn-xs btn-default push-20-r';
        }
    }),

    // other unrelated stuff...
});
```

Now here's my problem:
when `isSortableDown` is changing, `variableClassNames` in parent AND `classNames` in child (component/my-button) IS updated (also the test-output in my-button template).
**BUT** the classNameBindings are NOT updated, instead the classNames appear multiple times (when looking at the actual outputted DOM).
Well, that's not 100% right, they do get added, but never removed.
So if the className `push-20-r` once gets added, it'll stay there (in the DOM), but never removed, even if the property `classNames` doesn't include it anymore.

*Finally* my question is if I'm doing something wrong,
or if the classNameBindings *should* not be updated (but why the name 'bindings' then??),
or if this is eventually a bug?

*I'm on

Ember 2.0.1

jQuery 1.11.3*

The only maybe relevant issues I found are:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11980
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11556
but they don't have an answer... or are only party related

*Sidenote:*
Yes, I want the component itself to be a `button`, not a div, because otherwise I'd have to change all the css.... I know I could do it by leaving the component a div and wrap that button and adjust it's classNames there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using special property of ember component `classNames` as bound variable which was causing the problem instead you can take following approach

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'button',
    classNameBindings: ['isSortableDown::push-20-r'], // class added when isSortableDown is false 
    classNames: ['btn', 'btn-xs', 'btn-default'], // classes that don't change
    isSortableDown: true
    // some other unrelated stuff following....
});
```

in template

```
{{my-button
    isSortableDown=isSortableDown
    text='foo'
}}
```

in your parent component

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

    isSortableDown: Ember.computed('track.sort', 'maxSort', function() {
        return this.get('track.sort')<this.get('maxSort');
    }),

    // other unrelated stuff...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`classNames` is a special property within components. You might try changing the name to something else and see if that helps?

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_classNames

Comment: thank you for your answer, you are absolutely right! I still accept the other answer, as it is more complete.